# Elastic Search Fetch Exact document

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I've been trying to fetch document from elastic search on the basis of two fields "sAMAccountName" and "Container" but no luck. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtpLr.png)

What i want is a document where both attributes are exactly equally to my given value.
This is something I've been doing
It gave me results where user contain's the given property but i want exact match.

```
string container = getUserContainer(identityStore.ConnectionString);
var searchRequest = new Nest.SearchRequest();
searchRequest.Size = 10000;
searchRequest.Query = GetQuery(knownAttributes.SamAccountName, userName) && GetQuery("Container", container);
var searchResults = elasticSearch.Search<Dictionary<string,object>>(searchRequest);
                return null;

private Nest.MatchQuery GetQuery(Nest.Field field, string query)
{
            var matchQuery = new Nest.MatchQuery();
            matchQuery.Field = field;
            matchQuery.Query = query;
            matchQuery.Operator = Operator.And;
            r
```

eturn matchQuery;
        }

Comment: What does the mapping for the `user` type in the `adatum.local_1` index? Are `sAMAccountName` and `Container` mapped as `keyword` field types?

Comment: I am also trying to do the exact same thing. Take a look at my post [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865760/elasticsearch-nest-issue-trying-to-search-and-update-object-elk-6-x). Basically a reached a point that I used `keyword` notation, `.Term` query and `.Value` as suggested by Russ Cam but I still have the problem. I believe this might not be possible. Perhaps my POST example helps, let me know if you also find the solution in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IQueryResponse<T> result = client.Search<T>(s => s
                               .Size(1)                                   
                               .Query(q => q.Term("field1", value1) && q.Term("field2", value2))
                               .Index("myindex")
                               .Type("mytype")
                               );
                            if (result.Documents.Count<T>() > 0)
                            {
                               //do something                                    
                            }
```

Comment: There is an issue with this one. It gave me result where "field1" contains value1 but i need where "field1" is exactly equals to value1.

Comment: No, normally the term query returns the exact result, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Another possibility is, that you define your field in elasticsearch of type keyword. Then the text ist not analyzed and will not be tokenized, so you can run your term query, to find the exact match.